# Php Function not working properly

Tags: php, function

showcattable is to display a table now i'm calling dispcategoriesstate which will display state of the categories...On the output i'm getting categories state but after that further code execution stops..also no error.

function to show table

```
function showcattable($con){
    $i=2;
    $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categories");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select))
     { 
    echo"<tr>
        <td class='v-align-middle'><div class='checkbox check-default'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='".$row['cat_id']."' id='checkbox".$i."'>
        <label for='checkbox".$i."'></label>
        </div></td>
        <td class='v-align-middle'>".$row['category_title']." </td>
        <td class='v-align-middle'>".$this->dispcategoriesstate($row['cat_id'],$con);"</td>
        <td>
        <a href='edit_product.php?pro_id=18'>
        <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'/>
        </i></a> | 

        <a href='product.php?del_id=18&action=del' onclick=' return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');'>
        <i class='fa fa-close'/>
        </i>
        </a>
        </td>
        </tr>";
        $i++;

    }}
```

function to display state

```
function dispcategoriesstate($parent_id,$con) {

        $q="SELECT status FROM categories WHERE cat_id='".$parent_id."'";
        $select=mysqli_query($con,$q);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($select);
        if ($row['status']==1)
        {
            return 'active';    
        }
        else
        {
            return 'inactive';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error, semicolon is mistakely added

```
<td class='v-align-middle'>".$this->dispcategoriesstate($row['cat_id'],$con);"</td>
                                                                            ^
```

correct it as

```
<td class='v-align-middle'>".$this->dispcategoriesstate($row['cat_id'],$con)."</td>
```

Comment: Thanks it was a silly mistake...thanks again

Comment: @Nirajdev well if my answer is right please mark it as accepted ...see how here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work